# Ajustar espaço antes dos títulos

Tags: suporte, layout

### Ajustar espaço antes dos títulos:

Veja a explicação e o problema "ao vivo" aqui mesmo:

### Motivo:

O título "Motivo", por exemplo, está muito próximo do bloco de cima. Por lógica teria que ser mais espaçado do de cima do que deste bloco de texto aqui <==.

### Simulação da solução.

Neste título usei um <br> para descolar o "Simulação" do bloco de cima. Faz mais sentido o espaço maior, não? Não precisa ser tanto, claro. O importante é não precisar dessa gambiarra de <br>.

*A pedido do @Bacco*

Comment: Concordo, isso ou uma linha horizontal.